# Can't test controller render due to ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

Ok, I have this controller code:

```
def create
    @foo = Foo.new(user: User.new(user_params))
    if @foo.save
      redirect_to foos_path
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

And I would like to test if it re-renders the new page when the user email is invalid. To do that, I created this test:

```
it "should re-render the new template" do
    post :create, params: { user: attributes_for(:user, email: "abc.com") } }
    expect(response).to render_template(:new)
end
```

However, the test is failing due to this error:

```
 Failure/Error: if @foo.save

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (260, null).
   : INSERT INTO "foos" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

The Foo table has a

```
t.belongs_to :user, null: false, index: true
```

so that it does not add a foo without a user.

I think this error is actually a desired behavior, since it prevents the foo to be saved without a user and the user cant be saved with an invalid email. But I still need to test it, so am I testing it wrongly? How can I do that? Is there something missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I guess here is the error:

```
@foo = Foo.new(user: User.new(user_params))
```

`User.new` will not save the User to DB, so you will not have an ID and will fail your user_id non-null constraint.

Use:

```
user = User.create(user_params)
@foo = Foo.new(user: user)
```

instead

Comment: This is exactly the problem. But it should save it anyway.. I tried the way you suggested, assuming that the problem could be that it would try to save both at the same time, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I am guessing your user is not being save due to validation fails

Comment: Well, I changed my controller to do this:
    `if @foo.user.save && @foo.save`
instead of just
    `if @foo.save`
and it worked, but shouldn't they be quite the same?

Comment: @RafaelCosta, if `@foo.save` returns false, user will still be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@foo = Foo.new
@foo.build_user(user_params)
@foo.save
```

It should save both user and foo.

This will create a transaction so that it will not save any records to database until foo and user are validated.